# How to get the selected value of the radio button list in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html.radiobuttonlist

I have radio button list which has id as the value, I want to access the selected id in the jquery function.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If you have HTML that looks like this:

```
<input type='radio' name='choices' value='1'>
<input type='radio' name='choices' value='2'>
<input type='radio' name='choices' value='3'>
<input type='radio' name='choices' value='4'>
<input type='radio' name='choices' value='5'>
```

You would get the selected radio value with this:

```js
$("input:radio[name='choices']:checked").val();
```

Comment: $("input:radio[name='choices']:checked").val(); Might work better.

Comment: Agreed that `checked` works, `selected` does not (at least in Firefox 13, jQuery 1.8)

Answer (score 8):

It will get the selected value of the radiobutton at button click.
ex for list

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
   $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
});
```