# JQuery - Getting selected radio button value

Tags: jquery

My JQuery function looks like, where a$RadioBtn is the one only radio button list on my form:

```
IR.Web.cRptCtl.prototype.getSelectedRadioValue = function(a$RadioBtn){
  //Here I want to return a$RadioBtn's selected value
}
```

How do I determine the selected value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the selected value of the radio button list in jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743052/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-the-radio-button-list-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `a$RadioBtn` is a JQuery object of the radio elements, use:

```
a$RadioBtn.filter(":checked");
```

This will return a JQuery object, representing the selected radio input field. If you want to perform DOM operations on it, use the `.get(0)` method to get the DOM element.

Example:

```
IR.Web.cRptCtl.prototype.getSelectedRadioValue = function(a$RadioBtn){
    var selected = a$RadioBtn.filter(":checked");
    alert(selected.val());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name="your_radio_name"]).is('checked').val();
```

this will return value of your selected radio button

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name='name_of_radio']:checked").val();
```