# Radio buttons not working. Not sure if it the the buttons or my function

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I am trying to use radio buttons in html, but when I test out my code, what i want to happen isn't happening. I'm not sure if this is because of the radio buttons or the function i made. 
here are the radio buttons, along with some other inputs I have:

```
<input type="text" id="num1">
+<input type="radio" name="group1" id="add" value="add">
-<input type="radio" name="group1" id="subtract" value="subtract">
*<input type="radio" name="group1" id="multiply" value="multiply">
/<input type="radio" name="group1" id="divide" value="divide">
<input type="text" id="num2">
<input type="text" id="answer" readonly>
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="operation()"
```

And here is the function I made:

```
function operation() {
    if (document.getElementById("add").checked) {
        calculate0()
    }
    if (document.getElementById("subtract").checked) {
        calculate1()
    }
    if (document.getElementById("multiply").checked) {
        calculate2()
    }
    if (document.getElementById("divide").checked) {
        calculate3()
```

Thanks!

Comment: show your code in live jsFiddle.net

Comment: Where are the calculate() functions?

Comment: This will be helpful 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743052/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-the-radio-button-list-in-jquery

Comment: what happens if you put a console.log in each of your if statements?

Comment: @tilwinjoy The calculate functions already work, They're not the issue

Answer (score 1):

here's a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/7ss2S/).

modify your script as follows:

```
function operation() {
var ans =document.getElementById("answer");
if (document.getElementById("add").checked) {
    ans.value= calculate('add');
}
if (document.getElementById("subtract").checked) {
    ans.value= calculate('subtract');
}
if (document.getElementById("multiply").checked) {
    ans.value= calculate('multiply');
}
if (document.getElementById("divide").checked) {
    ans.value= calculate('divide');
}
}
function calculate(action){
        var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
        var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
        var result;
        switch(action){
            case 'add':
                result= parseInt(num1)+parseInt(num2);
                break;

            case 'subtract':
                result= num1-num2;
                break;

            case 'multiply':
                result= num1*num2;
                break;

            case 'divide':
                result= num1/num2;
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

*side note: now might be a good time to start closing the html tags*

Comment: @user2059810 would be nice if you accept the ans if it helped you!