# I want to use RadioButtons in a table, where only one is allowed to be selected

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, model-view-controller, radio-button

I have table with radiobuttons (one on each row).
They will start out unfilled.
Only one will be allowed to be clicked at one time.
And if I click a filled radio button it will clear it.

The app uses MVC, Razor, jQuery, C#.

Should I use jQuery with onclick or onload?
Should I use Razor? with .RadioButtonFor or .RadioButton?

```
                  <table id='id="rdBtnID1' cellpadding="3px" class="tableBorder" style="width: 90%" >
                         <tr style="background: #C3C3C3">
                              <th align="left">Click to pick one person to Marry</th>
                              <th align="left">Girls Name/th>
                              <th align="left">Phone Number</th>
                              <th align="left">Email</th>
                         </tr>
                         @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Girls)
                    </table>


Template
@model MarriageDatabase.Models.Girls    
<tr>
<td align="center" style="width:100px">
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GirlsID)
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.GirlPicked, false)
</div></td>
<td style="font-weight:normal">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.GirlsName)</td>
<td style="font-weight:normal">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.GirlsPhone)</td>
<td style="font-weight:normal">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.GirlsEmail)</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want what's more commonly called a Radio Button List. As long as the input name is the same for all the radios, you should only be able to select one.

Try this:
[How to get the selected value of the radio button list in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743052/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-the-radio-button-list-in-jquery)

Comment: Not a list, this will come from a database list. It is set to empty, When I click save later, it will save the results to the database.  For now all I need is how to edit the radio buttons that can be on multiple lines within the table.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot and maybe some code to your question? It might make the problem clearer.

Comment: <input id="RadioButton1" name="RadioButton1" type="radio" value="SelectedValue" />

Comment: last line posted works with multiple lines of a table. still need to set blank by clicking again.

Comment: to blank a radio you can use `.reset()` or set `.checked = false` in Javascript