# Mirror Radio button content

Tags: javascript, jquery

looking to mirror the value within the  of the checked radio box into the #result (red box).

Do you know how I can do this ?

```html
<div style="display: block;" id="block1">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="orderopt">
    <tr>
      <td class="orderopt-td1">
        <input type="radio" name="7x5" value="book>book 7x5 in. $1.00 " />
      </td>
      <td class="orderopt-td2">
        book cover 7x5 in. </td>
      <td class="orderopt-td3">$1.00</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="orderopt">
    <tr>
      <td class="orderopt-td1">
        <input type="radio" name="10x7" value="book>book  10x7 in. $2.00 " />
      </td>
      <td class="orderopt-td2">
        book cover 10x7 in. </td>
      <td class="orderopt-td3">$2.00</td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <div id="result" style="width: 200px; border:1px solid red;height: 30px;">result here </div>
```

Comment: Why do you have them as radio when they do not even behave like radio

Comment: To act as a real radio button (select single value) they must share the same name. To get the value of the selected item in a proper list of radio buttons use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743052/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-the-radio-button-list-in-jquery.

Comment: Wait!! have you tried anything? :)

Answer (score 1):

And for your weird use case if you want the following would work

```js
  function handle7x5(){
    ele = document.getElementById("result");
    ele.innerHTML = document.getElementsByName('7x5')[0].value;
  }

  function handle10x7(){
    ele = document.getElementById("result");
    ele.innerHTML = document.getElementsByName('10x7')[0].value;
  }
```

```html
<div style="display: block;" id="block1">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="orderopt">
    <tr>
        <td class="orderopt-td1">
            <input type="radio" name="7x5" value="book>book 7x5 in. $1.00 " onchange="handle7x5();"/>
        </td>
        <td class="orderopt-td2">
            book cover 7x5 in. </td>
        <td class="orderopt-td3">$1.00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="orderopt">
    <tr>
        <td class="orderopt-td1">
            <input type="radio" name="10x7" value="book>book  10x7 in. $2.00 " onchange="handle10x7();" />
        </td>
        <td class="orderopt-td2">
            book cover 10x7 in. </td>
        <td class="orderopt-td3">$2.00</td>
    </tr>
</table>


<div id="result" style="width: 200px; border:1px solid red;height: 30px;">result here </div>
```

Comment: Well, what if I have about 100 value ? do I have to write a function for each size?

Comment: No it's easy, that function can be made to a generic function and take arguments :)

Comment: ex:
function handleClick(param){
    ele = document.getElementById("result");
    ele.innerHTML = document.getElementsByName(param)[0].value;
  }

Then call it like this handleClick('7x5'); etc.